# Using Python to build a JSON file containing a list of keywords to be parsed through later

Tags: python, json

```
# List containing keywords to parse data from JSON file.
import json

keywords_list = []


def keyword_load():
    """Loads the JSON file to add keywords to."""
    with open('keywords.json') as kl:
        keywords_list = json.load(kl)
            
def keyword_add():
    """Asks users to add a new keyword."""
    new_word = input("\nAdd a keyword: ")
    keywords_list.append(new_word)

def keyword_show():
    """Shows the list of keywords."""
    print("\n======List of keywords======")
    [print(word) for word in keywords_list]

def keyword_write():
    """Function writes the list of keywords to JSON file."""
    with open('keywords.json', 'a+') as f:
        json.dump(keywords_list, f, indent=2)


#Program Begin...

print("Welcome to the Keyword Adding Module.\n")


keyword_show()

while True:
    keyword_load()
    add_word = input("\nWould you like to add another word? (y/n): ")
    
    if add_word == "y":
        keyword_add()
        keyword_show()
        keyword_write()

    elif add_word == "n":
        # If data entry is complete, write the list contents to JSON file.
        keyword_write()
        close = input("Hit enter to close.")
        break

    else:
        # In case a user responds with neither a 'y' or 'n'.
        print("\nATTENTION: Please enter 'y' or 'n'")
```

The program asks a user if they would like to add a keyword, upon 'y' input, the user is prompted to add a word... which is then displayed in the list.  The user can continue building the list as it is displayed above the prompt.  When the user enters 'n' to end adding words, a JSON file is written with the words.

Here's the problem, if the user runs the module again, when the words are added, it adds another JSON object without proper indentation and I get and 'unexpected end of file' error.  Additionally, I want all the words to be included in one single JSON object.  But in the end, I just want a list of words that can be added to by running this program.

If there's a better way, I'm all ears!

p.s. Python 3.10

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong....I want to keep the keywords created from one session and be able to be listed in a subsequent session and have those new keywords added the the end of the list.  I'm fine with rewriting the entire structure if that's what it means....again, so long nothing is over written/lost.

Comment: ok so with my with open() I should use the r+ parameter?   My other functions that contain the with statement, so could that be closing the file before I'm ready?  Not sure that's causing my file to be closed prematurely. Also...I don't expect the file to go beyond 100 words, although it may....but this also serves as form of practice but will be used for a real-world solution.

Comment: As an aside, the division of your program into functions is a good practice, but often, you want functions to encapsulate their logic to reusable parts, and have the I/O happen in the calling code. Currently `keywords_list` in the `keyword_load` code needs to be declared `global` for any of this to work, but a better design altogether would be for that function to (accept a file name as input argument, and) return the list of words to the caller, which removes the need for globals.

Comment: Also, the `close =` assignment is unnecessary; you can simply call `input("...")` and ignore its return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append to a JSON file, you have to overwrite it. JSON is a structured format which does not lend itself to easy amending (though you could have JSON *lines* format where every line of the file is an entire JSON structure, but then you'd have to write the output on a single line).

Since you are writing out the entire dictionary every time, appending to the previous list would have other problems, too (your deleted words would appear in the earlier versions of the data, and then your program would have to figure out how to only get the latest list when loading it).

The simple fix is to change the `open` mode from `'a+'` to `'w'`.

Since your data structure is trivial, an alternative fix would be to use a simple text file with one word per line, and only write out the new word(s). But then you'd still have to rewrite the entire file when you want to delete a word.

While working on your program, you could wreck the file if you have a bug which causes the writing function to fail. Other than that, overwriting the old data should be safe. Maybe take care to save a backup of the file every once in a while, or make sure you only use easily replaceable test data while developing.

Comment: Ok that does make sense, wasn't aware of those possibilities either.  I DID think of using a text file as it's easy to add to manually, but I was wondering if the JSON format would add some level of security.  But like you said, I could easily back it up and replace if it's ever necessary.  My main program is essentially a logbook type program where users can log date/time; problem/resolution/who fixed it by role/downtime associated.  Hence the keyword list, as the program will build a dashboard based on looking up the keywords in the problem entry and show top 10 problems, for example.

Comment: I will change the open mode to 'w' since I can load the previous list and just have the whole thing written over as you described.